# Armadillo: error when multiplying

Tags: c++, xcode, wrapper, armadillo

I'm using armadillo for a project, and in general it's been working well.  The project is Xcode based, and so far the only way I've managed to get it working is with (adding a header search path of /usr/include/ doesn't seem to work):

```
#include "/usr/include/armadillo"
```

Well now I'm trying to do some matrix multiplications for the first time, and I've done the simplest thing I could think of to make sure there's no other cause.

```
mat aa = eye(3,3)*eye(3,3);
```

but this gives me the linker error:

***"_wrapper_dgemm_", referenced from:**

```
void arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const*, char const*, int const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)in DynamicGridPoint.o
```

Anyone know what could be causing this?  The examples (which include matrix multiplication) compile just fine from the command line, so I assume this is to do with my xcode setup

***EDIT BASED ON ANSWERS SO FAR***

so I've tried to link to the run time library by including -larmadillo in the project's 'Other Linker Flags', and adding '/usr/lib' to the Header and Library search paths, but I get the link error: 'ld: library not found for -larmadillo'

any thoughts on why this could be happening?

/usr/lib contains the following (relevant) files:

- libarmadillo.3.80.2.dylib
- libarmadillo.3.dylib
- libarmadillo.dylib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not linking against the armadillo run-time library (eg. -larmadillo).

To fix this, either configure Xcode to link with the armadillo run-time library, or edit Armadillo's configuration so that it doesn't use its run-time library.

The latter is done via editing "include/armadillo_bits/config.hpp" and commenting out ARMA_USE_WRAPPER. You will then need to link against lapack and blas directly (eg. -llapack -lblas), or use the Accelerate framework  (eg. -framework Accelerate).

Comment: so I've tried to link to the run time library by including -larmadillo in the project's 'Other Linker Flags', and adding '/usr/lib' to the Header and Library search paths, but I get the link error:

'ld: library not found for -larmadillo'

any thoughts on why this could be happening?  /usr/lib contains the following files:

libarmadillo.3.80.2.dylib
libarmadillo.3.dylib
libarmadillo.dylib

Comment: I've now successfully tried explicitly linking against lapack and blas (with -llapack -lblas), but I'm curious as to why this works and -larmadillo doesn't...  if you have any ideas that would be great, but either way, thanks for a working solution!

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the armadillo shared library. In the Makefile in the examples, the rules to make are:

```
all: example1 example2                                                          

example1: example1.cpp  
  $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS)  -o $@  $<  $(LIB_FLAGS)
```

`LIB_FLAGS` is defined earlier as

```
LIB_FLAGS = -larmadillo $(EXTRA_LIB_FLAGS)

ifeq (macos,macos)                                                              
  EXTRA_LIB_FLAGS = -framework Accelerate                                     
endif
```

So in your XCode project you need to find a way to include libarmadillo. The Accelerate framework is optional; I've never used it.

Comment: thanks for a tip - any ideas why the approach I'm taking to include libarmadillo (see edit to question) might not be working?

Comment: Seems correct ... The only thing I can think of is that you need to specify the link paths _after_ the source file because some compilers use the source file to decide whether or not to link to a specified library. In my example above, $(LIB_FLAGS) comes after $< (which denotes the first file in the dependency, which is example1.cpp)

Comment: xcode decides what order the flags should be in, so it should put the linker flags in the correct place